# Creating executable with Cx_freeze : ImportError: cannot import name _ni_support (scipy)

Tags: python, scipy, cx-freeze

I am trying to create an executable from a python script, I have had a few issues that I have solved simply manually importing other modules/scripts, but for some reason it doesn't worth with this one. The error message:

```
File "C:\Program Files\Miniconda2\lib\site-packages\scipy\ndimage\filters.py", line 35, in <module>
from . import _ni_support
ImportError: cannot import name _ni_support
```

Did anyone have this problem before? I can't seem to find it anywhere online. (I found similar problems with _ni_support but never with scipy.

I already tried reinstalling every package/module, but the problem is still there.

Thank you all for your patience.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Solved:**

For some unknow reason I had the following unused import added to my script a couple commits earlier:

```
from skimage.feature.tests.test_censure import img
```

**Removing it solved the issue.**